# Can I parse the directory listing of an external webpage?

Tags: php

Is it possible to parse the directory listing of a webpage which is external given the webpage is accessible and it shows a list of the files when I access it. I only want to know is it possible to parse the files dynamically in PHP and how? -thank you

Sorry for being not clear. I mean a directory listing such as:
http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/ (Index of /..) and ability to read the content as array or something easy to manipulate in my script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

For your case:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/");
preg_match_All("|href=[\"'](.*?)[\"']|", $contents, $hrefs);
var_dump($hrefs);
```

If you want to take a look at a [working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/15945.php).

Comment: Can we do this with guzzle ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a directory listing back that is full of links in a proper XHTML document you can use `DOMDocument`, and code such as the following to get back a list of files:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhitespace = false;
$doc->load('directorylisting.html');

$files = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

`$files` is now a list of `DOMElement`s that you can iterate through and get the `href` attribute to get a full path to the files in the listing.

Note that this approach **requires** a properly formed directory listing returned from the server. You cannot, for example, do a request on `stackoverflow.com` and get a directory listing of the files.

If this doesn't work (perhaps malformed HTML) you could use Regular Expressions (eg. `preg_match_all`) to find `<a` tags, like such:

```
preg_match_all('@<a href\="([a-zA-Z\.\-\_\/ ]*)">(.*)</a>@', file_get_contents('http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/'), $files);
var_dump($files);
```

`$files` would still be matched elements, just a set of arrays.

---

UPDATE, I tested with your URL (`http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/`) and it works fine (the `preg_match_all` method).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible.  I'm not quite clear what you mean by directory listing but you should research website crawlers.  This is essentially what you're asking about but written in PHP.

Comment: I think he wants to parse Apache directory listing (Options +Indexes)

Comment: I mean directory listing.. a directory containing files (say images folder) on external domain and I need to read the images on my script ,etc.

Answer (score 0):

PHP [file_get_content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will do the trick for you.

(Assuming your http request for this page returns the listing of files, as you have mentioned)

Comment: Yes I am sure the page returns listing of files with Index of / etc etc. It did the trick thanks, now any way to convert this to array or something to read each file in the listing individually?

Comment: Conversion to array ----------You can split with a separator , in our case separator will be "\n" I guess