# Is there a way to screen scrape a directory listing?

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I have a server that has a directory listing for a "webpage."  I have no control over the server or the output.  They just drop a file in a directory and since they have directory listing turn on, it shows up in the list.  As you can imagine, it is a mess.

Is there anyway I can consume that directory listing and put it in some form that is usable?  Their server is IIS if that matters.

I will be using PHP on IIS (different server).  I am thinking I can use curl, but am not sure, and don't know what I'd do.  I'd like to be able to sort by alphabetical filename or date.

Thanks for any help.

edit:  I tried the information in the answer here:

[Can I parse the directory listing of an external webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773605/can-i-parse-the-directory-listing-of-an-external-webpage)

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/");
preg_match_All("|href=[\"'](.*?)[\"']|", $contents, $hrefs);
var_dump($hrefs);
```

I was returned:

```
 array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }
```

The page is just the standard IIS listing.  It has the date, time, size, and then the html link to the file.  It is a standard href link.

so a link in the page in question looks like this:

```
<A HREF="/">[To Parent Directory]</A>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I parse the directory listing of an external webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773605/can-i-parse-the-directory-listing-of-an-external-webpage)

Comment: This should be just a simple cURL/DOM job. Just cURL to get the contents of the page (or even [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if you're lazy), pass the resulting string into [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and then (probably) [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) will help you easily collect the data you want into an array. Then you should be able to [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) it into the order you want. I can't give example code without seeing the dir listing page.

Comment: @JRL  I tried the example given.  It did not work.  I get:  array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: The chances are not good that IIS' file listing HTML is well-formed enough to be parsed by PHP's DOMDocument.  But anything can be scraped.  If you show your sample HTML and the code you've attempted to scrape it with so far, I'm sure you'll get more help, including perhaps some actual *answers*.

Comment: Jonny, take a look at a product I've developed might help you grab the content into Excel.  The example projects might give you an idea.[Script Scraper] (http://www.scriptscraper.com)